# Why i can't to update nested serializer by id?

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

When i send data throw PUT request this `id` can't get this `id` in validated data. 
For example body of PUT request:

```
{
  "slug": "string",
  "company_id": 1,
  "api_secret": "string",
  "merchant_url_list": [
    { 
      "id": 1
      "merchant_url_type_id": 1,
      "url": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

But in validated_data `{'slug': 'string', 'company': <Company: Company object (1)>, 'api_secret': 'string', 'merchanturl_set': [OrderedDict([('merchant_url_type', <MerchantUrlType: Бот (None)>), ('url', 'string')])]}`
There is not `id`. How i can get id?

```
class MerchantUrlSerializer(IdModelSerializer):
    merchant = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MerchantUrl
        fields = ('id', 'merchant_url_type', 'merchant', 'url')


class MerchantSerializer(NestedSerializerMixin, IdModelSerializer):
    merchant_url_list = MerchantUrlSerializer(source='merchanturl_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = ('id', 'slug', 'company', 'api_secret', 'merchant_url_list')
```

```
{
  "slug": "string",
  "company_id": 0,
  "api_secret": "string",
  "merchant_url_list": [
    {
      "merchant_url_type_id": 0,
      "url": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pk` field - `id` in your case - is `read_only` by default since it represents the PK.

If you want to alter that behaviour, you'll need to set it read/write:

```
class MerchantUrlSerializer(IdModelSerializer):
    merchant = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MerchantUrl
        fields = ('id', 'merchant_url_type', 'merchant', 'url')
        extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': False}}
```